# koltin I understand the clickListener function

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I would like to get more information about this function, doesn't it take an anonym function?

```
class DevByteCountryPropertyListener(val clickListener: (countryId : String ) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick(devByteCountryProperty: DevByteCountryProperty) = clickListener(devByteCountryProperty.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the `clickListener` parameter in the constructor, that's not an actual function - it's a function *type*. You're just describing what the function passed in should look like.

When you want to call that constructor and pass in a function, that's when you decide if you're passing in an anonymous function, or a lambda, or a function reference. There's no difference inside `DevByteCountryPropertyListener` - `clickListener` is always just a function that takes a `String` and doesn't return anything, it doesn't know or care how that function was defined and created.

Here's the documentation on [anonymous functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions) - like it says, it's basically a lambda except you can define the return type, and it's a lot less concise and readable. It's called *anonymous* because you're not actually naming the function - so you can't refer to it anywhere else, you use it as soon as you create it, e.g. passing it into this constructor.